# Do friendly kills reset your scorestreak meter?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

In **Call Of Duty: Black Ops 3**, it is possible to kill your teammate in the [Hardcore](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hardcore) game mode.

What I want to know is whether or not my scorestreak meter resets if one of my teammates accidentally (or intentionally, who knows) kills me in the field of combat. I wouldn't be too entirely sure because my first scorestreak is the Cerberus and the game mode limits the player's HUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hardcore mode if someone on your team accidentally kills you, your scorestreak meter will reset. Here's some other peoples opinions on Reddit.

> [Reddit: Team Kills In Hardcore Resetting Scorestreaks](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackops3/comments/3va8um/hc_team_kills_shouldnt_reset_your_killstreak_also/)